# How to deploy RDLC files with visual-studio 2010 setup

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, rdlc, setup-deployment

I am developing a windows app where many `.rdlc` are there in a "report" folder of that project. When I create a setup for delivery to the client, do I need to include all those .rdlc file manually or will they be included automatically just like .rpt (crystal report) files?

What I could do: as a result always include .rdlc files automatically, when I batch build my project. Can anyone guide me?

I asked the same thing in another forum and got the following guidance:

> ...found that reports tend to grow, usually AFTER the application has been deployed and has been used for some time. Also if you have different customers they often want distinct reports.
>
> I had all my reports in a table, all records had a stored procedure name and a file name, if the file existed and the procedure existed the report could execute.
>
> I could then distribute a new report without having to recompile and distribute the app. Simple deliver the file and a script to create the stored procedure and report record.

But I want to know about *RDLC*, which is client side. I asked how I could distribute my `rdlc` files with my application setup, so that as a result when a client installs my setup he can view the report which is based on rdlc. I'd like to know what (if any) is the industry standard for including rdlc files into a setup project. If anyone knows about such a thing then please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone gets to this post, as I did, this question has already being answered in a duplicate post:

[Publishing RDLC files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481223/publishing-rdlc-files)

I had the same problem, and it worked for me. Hope it helps anyone who comes across this post