# need help on Using and Publishing rdlc file

Tags: visual-studio-2017, rdlc, reportviewer

I need a help on using rdlc file in my windows application created in VS 2017 environment.

I read similar thing on [Publishing RDLC files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481223/publishing-rdlc-files) but not sure how to use ReportPath, my current code is as follow and works great from visual studio on my machine and I am sure it wont work on client's machine after deployment.

MyRptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + "/Reports/MyReport.rdlc";

Does installation create Reports folder and copy .rdlc file to local machine on installation?

I would appreciate if someone can guide me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the rdlc file build action to "embedded resources"

[image]

and use `Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "{AssemblyName}.{ReportName}.rdlc"` ,
this will work without need to copy the report to local machine on installation

Comment: Found this solution somewhere else and I applied it and it worked like charm. Thank you very much looking into it.