# how to make a local report processing work on client system

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Am having an error showing report printing on client computer including my very own computer after have published the application. See the errors information below

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

this code up there was asked by me to put  on the main entry point of the application when i install report viewer runtime on my vs2019 enterprise which i did.

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing. ---> System.ApplicationException: The report definition for report '0000_680251\Reports\PurchaseCostCalculation' has not been specified ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.StandalonePreviewStore.GetReportDefinition(PreviewItemContext itemContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.StandalonePreviewStore.GetReportDefinition(PreviewItemContext itemContext)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.GetCompiledReport(PreviewItemContext itemContext, Boolean rebuild, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CompileReport()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.Microsoft.Reporting.ILocalProcessingHost.CompileReport()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at brothers.Forms.Purchase_Cost_Calculation.btnviewdatagrid_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4180.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
brothers
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/9H5GTLQ1.WDN/8YCH48BB.64V/brot..tion_9c910aff62934c64_0001.0000_68025146b8327407/brothers.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4150.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4001.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4121.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4180.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Caching
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Caching/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Runtime.Caching.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
    Assembly Version: 15.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 15.0.1404.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/9H5GTLQ1.WDN/8YCH48BB.64V/brot..tion_9c910aff62934c64_0001.0000_68025146b8327407/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
    Assembly Version: 15.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 15.0.1404.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/9H5GTLQ1.WDN/8YCH48BB.64V/brot..tion_9c910aff62934c64_0001.0000_68025146b8327407/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

this was the code i used on visual studio and it working but it not working when i published on  client computer

```
reportpurchase.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
                string fullpath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath).Remove(path.Length - 10) + @"\Reports\PurchaseCostCalculation.rdlc";
                reportpurchase.LocalReport.ReportPath = fullpath;
                reportpurchase.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                reportpurchase.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("purchaseCost", dt));
                ReportParameter FromDate = new ReportParameter("FromDate", datefrom.Text.ToString());
                ReportParameter ToDate = new ReportParameter("ToDate", dateto.Text.ToString());
                this.reportpurchase.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { FromDate, ToDate });
                this.reportpurchase.RefreshReport();
                reportpurchase.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
                reportpurchase.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.PageWidth;
```

so how do i show the report on client system?? or how should i have specified the report path, this is a winforms application.

Comment: Focus on this: Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath).Remove(path.Length - 10)  I suspect this is not working the way you expect it.   This needs to be the full path and not:
0000_680251\Reports\PurchaseCostCalculation

Comment: @Pete-S- any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had follow the link Pete gave me and noticed that some folders are not in the publish folder. So I had to edit the csproj file of the project. You can access it by
1.right click on solution folder view, switch views to folder views and u should be able to see the projectname.csproj.
2. Click on it and close to the end of file, you should start seeing

```
<ItemGroup>blablabla</ItemGroup>
```

So write the code there

```
<ItemGroup>
 <Content Include="foldername\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

That all using Pete code to get the path of your folder

Answer (score 0):

After commenting through this issue, take a look at this: [Publishing RDLC files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481223/publishing-rdlc-files)

The full path to the report does not look valid:

For the executing path, I use [BaseDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.basedirectory?view=netframework-4.8):

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory()
```

Instead of manually concatenating the path, use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8)

```
string fullpath = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory(), "Reports\PurchaseCostCalculation.rdlc");
```

Comment: it didnt work, could not find the path when i debug on visual studio

Comment: In VS, the BaseDirectory is your debug folder where your .exe is generated, make sure you have the same sub-folder and file (Reports\PurchaseCostCalculation.rdlc).

Comment: This issue trips up from time to time as well, I'll put a breakpoint and get the value of the fullPath variable and paste it into Windows Explorer or Run and the path will appear, to keep me sane that in fact, it is valid  There have been times I SWORE that it was right and in the end, it wasn't (off by one character, etc).

Comment: actually, i copied the folder and subfolders int the bin directory just now and it works in visual studio, but after i published it, i cant find the report folders in the publish file, visual studio is not adding the folders in the publish folder, i dont know why??

Comment: or do i have to do some things so Vs can automatically add my folders

Comment: Yes, you will have to include these file(s) in order to publish them.

Comment: Here is an existing answer on what you need to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481223/publishing-rdlc-files

Comment: Thanks , I appreciate even , it didn't work either..I had to edit the csproj file and write some codes in it...Thanks anyway you gave me clue